# What does ここじゃ何だ means in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, expressions

> 「そ、そうか。何か大変そうだな……**ここじゃ何{なん}だ**、取りあえず私の店まで来いよ」

I couldn't find the meaning...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ここじゃ何だ

is, as I recognize, to be an abbreviated expression of

ここじゃ何かとアレだ

which I would translate to

```
In this place, in many ways, you know,,,
```

(I know my English is very awkward here...

Answer (score 9):

> ここじゃ**何**だ、取りあえず私の店まで来いよ

According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> なに【何】〘代名詞〙
>   ❷ 相手がそれと分かる事物について、名前の代わりに使う語。例のもの。あれ。また、**物事を直接的に指すのを避けて遠回しに言う語**。「いつもの、何はあるかな」「うちの何が、うるさくてね」「**お言葉を返すようでなんですが**…」「**自分で言うのもなんですが**…」

You use 何 to avoid referring to something directly, and to say it in a roundabout way / indirectly. Examples:

> こう言っては**なん**ですが・・・
>   If I may venture to say this... / If you'll excuse the expression...
>   自分で言うのも**なん**ですが・・・
>   Though I say it myself... / Though I say this who shouldn't...

---

By the way, you can use あれ in the same way. 明鏡国語辞典 says:

> あれ〘代名詞〙
>   ❶㋓ はっきり言えないことや、うまく言えないことを指し示す語。**なん**。「直接申し上げるのも**あれ**ですが…」

Comment: 私の認識がちょっと間違っていた様子ですね…

Comment: @YukiInoue いあいあ、そんなことないよ、気にしたらアカン ＾＾

Answer (score 5):

> http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/165822/meaning/m0u/ 
>   なん‐だ【何だ】    ［連語］《「だ」は断定の助動詞》
>
> (２).  直接言うのがはばかられたり、適当な言い方が見つからなかったりする場合に、代わりに用いる語。
>   「自分で言うのも ― が、僕ならできる」 「つまりは、 ― 、もうやめたいということか」

- This place is [You know what].
- This place is [I don't want to say what].
- This place is [What you might call it].

The meaning is :  This place is [not good] or [not convenient].

Was there an expression like this in Genji ?