# Meaning of a pattern "AといえばAにも見える"

Tags: meaning

I've came across a sentence

> 悪手【あくしゅ】といえば悪手【あくしゅ】にも見える

in a manga, but I can't find any explanation on this pattern, so I don't see how "speaking of" makes sense. A "bad move" isn't mentioned previously.

The character thinks "The last move was pretty interesting", and continues thinking on the next panel with the mentioned sentence.

The official English translation is

> "Most would consider it to be a bad move",

but I feel like there's more to the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ～といえば is not "speaking of ～", but simply "if someone says ～".

> 悪手といえば悪手にも見える
>   It might look like a bad move if someone says so.

In this case it means something like "it may look like a bad move at first sight, but I think it's actually interesting". Depending on the context, the same sentence can mean something like "it looked like a good move at first sight, but since you say it's bad, it started to appear bad".

For the usage of this も, see: [I need help understanding the grammar in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56449/5010)