# ～なくもない vs ～なくはない

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> 自信がなく**も**ない
>
> 自信がなく**は**ない

What's the difference here? I understand that both constructions are basically double negatives that cancel themselves into positives, with は sandwitched there to emphasize the negative. But the question is, what is も's purpose here, and what's the difference in meaning between the two constructions?

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56449/5010

Comment: Both sentences means the speaker is pretty confident, but with も, the sentence sounds more reserved ("I *would* say...", "well, ...", etc)

Comment: Found a good explanation here, if anyone's interested too: [double negative](https://maggiesensei.com/2015/09/09/double-negative-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-nainai/)