# Understanding ことでもあるまい in this context

Tags: grammar

> 「市民どもの同情ごっこの後に、それ以上果たせる役目がなければ、そうなるやもしれんな」
>
> 冷えた目を向けたシンに、参謀長は動じもしない。
>
> 「今更憤る**ことでもあるまい**、エイティシックス。人はそういうものだと思い知らされた果てが、今の君たちだろう」
>
> 86─エイティシックス─Ep.4　─アンダー・プレッシャー─ 安里アサト

Does the bold part mean ことはないだろう or 必要もないだろう?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's roughly the same as 今更憤ることでもないだろう. まい is an auxiliary for negative inference (=ないだろう) and negative volition (=ないつもりだ). It attaches to the dictionary (終止) form of verbs, but it can attach also to す and the pre-nai (未然) form of ichidan verbs. まい sounds fairly stilted, and it's no longer used in real-life conversations.

- 行くまい = 行かないだろう
- しまい = すまい = するまい = しないだろう
- 見まい = 見るまい = 見ないだろう
- 食べまい = 食べるまい = 食べないだろう

<sub>(Some dictionaries including [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%84/) do not allow 見るまい/食べるまい for ichidan verbs, but in my opinion, 見るまい/食べるまい is more natural than 見まい/食べまい in modern Japanese. See [this article](https://japanknowledge.com/articles/blognihongo/entry.html?entryid=334) and [this article](https://www.ytv.co.jp/michiura/time/2012/10/post-1346.html) for details.)</sub>

Comment: Thank you. But I'm still not sure about the ことでもない, especially でも. Are the ことでもない and ことはない (必要はない) the same? If not, what is the difference between them?

Comment: @chinoalpha 憤ることでもない is a [reserved](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83654/5010) version of 憤ることではない, which literally translates to "It's not something you'll be angry at".