# Meaning of 〜はしまいか、〜はすまいか、〜ていはしまいか and 〜ていはすまいか

Tags: grammar, meaning

I've found a couple of times while reading novels the grammar patterns

Verb stem + はしまいか/はすまいか

and

Verb て + いはしまいか/いはすまいか

However, I googled these patterns, but I couldn't find any website explaining them.

Could you please tell me about their meaning and give me an example of how are they used (if possible, I would like to see some any other sentence to have it as reference)?

Comment: For grammatical/historical details, you can see https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/2936938.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a fixed pattern with an idiomatic meaning, but a combination of simple rules. Taking 食べる as an example verb, 食べはすまい is just 食べはする with まい (negative inference) and か (question marker) attached. 食べていはする is 食べていはする with まい and か.

- 食べはする and so on are ways of attaching は (contrastive), も ("also/even") and すら ("even") to a verb. For example, `食べる + は` becomes `食べはする` ("eat at least"), `食べる + も` becomes `食べもする` ("also eat"), `食べる + すら + ない` becomes `食べすらしない` ("not even eat"). See also: [What's the grammatical breakdown of "知りもしないわ"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21075/5010)
- 食べはし**まい** (or 食べはすまい, 食べはするまい) is a negative inference version of 食べはする. しまい, すまい and するまい are interchangeable. It means 食べはしないだろう. For details, see [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/96027/5010).
- か is a question marker.

Therefore, 食べはしまいか is roughly the same as 食べはしないだろうか or 食べないだろうか ("Won't he eat it?", "I'm afraid that he will eat it").

If there's also a progressive meaning, just replace 食べる to 食べている and follow the same pattern:

- 食べている: is eating
- 食べていはする: is eating (at least)
- 食べていはしまい: it's not likely that he is eating
- 食べていはしまいか: isn't it likely that he is eating?

食べていはしまいか is roughly the same as 食べていはしないだろうか or 食べていないだろうか ("I wonder if he's eating?", "I'm afraid that he may be eating it").

Comment: Are すまい and しまい the same here? I would otherwise expect しまい in this position to be 仕舞い.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've explained it in my answer. See the second bullet. まい has nothing to do with (-て)しまう.

Comment: Ah, an unfortunate phonetic overlap, then. する seems to cause a lot of problems like that.

Comment: @naruto Thank you very much for your answer. Your breakdown of the structures helped me a lot to understand how are they formed and their meaning. :)

Comment: @naruto Is this common today, or perhaps a bit dated? I don’t think I’ve encountered it in speech or in literature.

Comment: ”食べていはする” is actually grammatical? I had always assumed the “topical form” of “食べている” is “食べてはいる” because one actually encounters it and with that meaning.  Is there a difference in your opinion between “〜てはいる” and “〜ていはする”?

Comment: @Zorf Yes, but it's much less common. Another example is at the end of [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/101538/5010). [This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/100239/5010) is related.