# What is the grammatical function of this part with しか

Tags: grammar

> 単語は、自分で努力して覚えるしか、習得の方法はない

What's the grammatical function of 「自分で努力して覚えるしか」? Is it the 連用修飾語 to modify 「習得の方法はない」？

Answer (score 2):

The 習得の方法は part can be placed before the しか clause, so I think it's a 連用修飾語 that modifies ない. You can also say the following without changing the meaning of the sentence:

> (単語の)習得の方法は、自分で努力して覚えるしかない。

The word しか by itself is classified as a 副助詞 (often translated as "adverbial particle"). Unlike 格助詞 ("case particle"), 副助詞 adds a certain meaning/mood to the word it modifies. Many 副助詞 can modify both a noun and a verb, and it often replaces が and を (が and を are case particles).

| 副助詞 | Marking subject | Marking object | Marking verb | Marking other 連用修飾語 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **も** | 彼も来る。 | リンゴも食べる。 | 本を読みもする。 | 家からも見える。 |
| **すら** | 彼すら来る。 | リンゴすら食べる。 | 本を読みすらする。 | 家からすら見える。 |
| **さえ** | 彼さえ来る。 | リンゴさえ食べる。 | 本を読みさえする。 | 家からさえ見える。 |
| **は** | 彼は来る。 | リンゴは食べる。 | 本を読みはする。 | 家からは見える。 |
| **しか** | 彼しか来ない。 | リンゴしか食べない。 | 本を読むしかしない。 | 家からしか見えない。 |

You can see しか is very close to other 副助詞, except that it is always used with a negation ([negative-polarity item](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/5010)) and that it can directly take a clause without a nominalizer.

Comment: Thanks! If the sentence were 「単語は、自分で努力して覚えるしか、習得の方法**が**ない」, the word order could still change? If not, the しか clause will modify 習得の方法がない?

Comment: @shepherd Yes, "単語は、習得の方法が自分で努力して覚えるしかない" is a valid sentence with the same meaning (it's a little harder to read, though).

Comment: OK, I understand. And is there any difference between 本を読むしか**し**ない and 本を読むしかない?

Comment: @shepherd 本を読むしかない = there is no option but for reading, all I can do is read; 本を読むしかしない = to do nothing but reading = to do only reading.