# What does Adjective + もならない mean?

Tags: negation, i-adjectives

。。。結局私は利用されてただけなんだな

"In the end, I was just being used use."

悲しくもならないや

Purely from context she seems to be saying "It doesn't even make me sad/I can't even get sad about it"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the sentence means "(it's so unexpected/unrealistic that) it doesn't even make me sad".

Without も, 悲しくならない(や) should be easy: "I won't get sad" or "it doesn't make me sad". Here, も has been inserted after 悲しく to add the nuance of "even". [This chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/100239/5010) may help you understand the grammar of this も.