# What is the role of まで in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-まで

I am not sure about the function of the second まで in the last sentence below:

> 美少女ゲームの創生期で、最も重要な作品と言えば・・・「プリンセスメーカー」、それと「同級生」と言えるでしょう! 究極、この2つだけでも現在までのゲーム**まで**全部語れるといっても過言ではない。

I think the second まで marks an object for 語れる? In this case, 現在までのゲームまで全部語れる should mean something like "serve as a model for modern games." In other words, the overall structure of modern games hasn't changed much from the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. This sentence looks slightly clumsy to me, but the two まで are used in different ways:

- The first まで is a particle meaning "until". 現在までのゲーム is "games up to the present".
- The second まで is "even", which is a [副助詞](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/100239/5010) that can replace が/を. So 現在までのゲーム is the direct object of 語れる. The author is saying you can explain/discuss all the past (bishōjo) games only by mentioning the two games.