# How to use the addition particle も on a whole sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-も, nominalization

> A: 先週の試験で一人だけ悪い成績だったのは、Cさんだそうだ。*On last week's exam, (I heard) only one person had bad results: Mr.C.*
>
> B: そうか。Cさんといえば、彼女と別れたらしい。*Really. Talking about Mr.C, (I heard he) broke up with (his) girlfriend.*
>
> B: そうか。Cさんといえば、入院したらしい。*Really. Talking about Mr.C, (I heard he) was hospitalised.*
>
> B: そうか。Cさんといえば、勉強しないらしい。*Really. Talking about Mr.C, (I heard he) doesn't study.*

I would like to add an additive nuance to the above responses from B using the も particle.

> I heard he broke up with his girlfriend *too*.
>
> I heard he was hospitalised *too*.
>
> I heard he *also* doesn't study.

However, as I understood it, も applies to a noun rather than applying to the whole sentence.

In the first response, how would one insert も? The only contender I see would be 「彼女と」 which could be turned to 「彼女とも」. However, wouldn't this be appropriate only when the subject breaks up with multiple people? As in, "with his girlfriend too, he broke up". How would one apply the additive factor to the whole activity, that is breaking up, rather than the target of the break up?

In the other two responses, there does not seem to be any space to insert a も at all.

So, is it impossible to use も that way, and should an adverb be used instead? What is the most natural way native speakers achieve that meaning?

Additionally, I thought of using the following construction, but I was told it was incorrect, though I ignore the reason why.

> そうか。Cさんといえば、彼女と別れた**こともある**らしい。
>
> そうか。Cさんといえば、入院する**こともある**らしい。

Comment: I think that it you can use way from "Marking verb" column in table in https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/100239/ (e.g. 「…彼女と別れもしたらしい。」).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific examples, it would be best to not express the additive nuance at all. 彼女と別れた and so on can serve as a reason for his bad test score, and they don't go well with も. Adding も will indicate that his bad score and his breakup are unrelated, which can be a little puzzling. Just saying "Cさんといえば彼女と別れたらしい" would be the most natural.

But this does not mean you cannot apply も to verbs. Here's how you can do it:

- For ordinary verbs, you can use `masu-stem + も + する`. See [this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/100239/5010) for similar patterns.

  > 笑う → 笑いもする also/even laugh
  > 見る → 見もする also/even look
  > 食べる → 食べもする also/even eat
- For suru-verbs, you can simply add も before する.

  > 勉強する → 勉強もする
- These can be negated with しない, but in such cases も tends to carry a nuance of "(not) even".

  > 笑いもしない not even laugh
  > 勉強もしない not even study

Examples:

- その本は知っていますし、実際に読みもしました。
  I know that book, and I also actually read it.
- 映画を見もしないで批判をするな。
  Don't criticize the movie without even watching it.

You cannot use こともある in this context because [ことがある](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B-ta-koto-ga-aru-meaning/) has a meaning you don't want here. 彼女と別れたこともある would mean "he has even experienced a breakup (in his whole life)", and 入院することもある would mean "he may sometimes be hospitalized, too".

Lastly, don't forget that you can always use independent words such as しかも and それに, too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In the first example, I wanted to imbue the response with a sense of abundance--"I heard he broke up with his girlfriend too (that's not one but two misfortunes, isn't he unlucky?)".

In that case, is adding しかも or using 別れもする the most natural move? Or do you still think it would sound strange to try to force that meaning upon that sentence in particular?

Lastly, that is the first time I've seen this stem+もする construction, could it be that it is rarely used or that other constructions are preferred in general?

Comment: @82474070449770901951 In your case, I think it's best to use しかも which can explicitly carry a nuance of "moreover". But `stem + もする` isn't particularly uncommon, especially in the negative form (もしない).