# Difference between のは and のも？

Tags: grammar

I came across this sentence:

> この齢で言う**のも**なんですが、私は幼さなど
> とっくに捨て切っていたつもりでした。

Could のは also be used here? And if so, what's the difference in nuance?

Comment: Yes, のは can be used here. You can see lots of similar questions here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/55970?lq=1

Comment: @Blake この「[何]{なん}ですが」の意味は、分かります？　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55361/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40005/9831

Comment: はい、分かります。でも、そのスレッドを読んでそれについてもっと学びました。ありがとうございます。